# drupal 7, db_select(), strange behavior : malformed query

Tags: 7, database

I have a table: mantenimiento_extras.

I want a query like this: select * from mantenimiento_extras where id in (7, 9).
(this case assumes passing array(7, 9), but it could be variable, even including the case for "in ()".

I execute this query:

```
db_select("mantenimiento_extras")->fields("mantenimiento_extras")->condition("id", $values, 'IN')->execute();//$values is guaranteed to be an array.
```

I get this query, and an error:

```
SELECT mantenimiento_extras.* FROM {mantenimiento_extras} mantenimiento_extras WHERE (id IN ()); Array( )
```

I modify the dynamic query:

```
db_select("mantenimiento_extras")->condition("id", $values, 'IN')->execute();
```

I get this query, and an error:

```
SELECT FROM {mantenimiento_extras} mantenimiento_extras WHERE (id IN ()) ; Array ( )
```

Now I bang my head against the nearest object in my desk.

Why is it generating malformed queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is *empty*, you'll get `WHERE foo IN ()`. That's invalid SQL syntax.

To prevent, use a conditional:

```
if (!empty($values)) {
  // Run the query.
}
```

Comment: I had to change the query and not use the dynamic query since {mantenimiento_extras} was also not accepted. Even having more weird results when trying different alternatives, getting stuff like "SELECT FROM {mantenimiento_extras}" ... i fell back to hard-coding the query.

But yes, that's another issue i got in my query.